# Nginx - rule interferes with http caching of other rule

Tags: nginx

I have these rules in nginx config:

```
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|mp4|bmp|gif|ico|woff|ttf|svg|otf)$ {
             expires max;
             access_log off;
             log_not_found off;
             add_header Pragma public;
             add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* /z.gif {
            empty_gif;
            etag off;
            add_header Pragma no-cache;
            add_header Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate";
    }
```

I do not want browser to cache z.gif. This works fine until former rule interferes with latter.

How to make them work?

Comment: I don't know for certain with nginx (since I haven't used it enough), but I'm used to things like apache doing first match... did you try reversing the order of your rules

Comment: yes, it works but when alot of request are made to pages. I can't find z.gif to load that many times in access.log